# Finding duplicate columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a pretty big data.table (500 x 2000), and I need to find out if any of the columns are duplicates, i.e., have the same values for all rows. Is there a way to efficiently do this within the data.table structure?

I have tried a naive two loop approach with `all(col1 == col2)` for each pair of columns, but it takes too long. I have also tried converting it to a data.frame and using the above approach, and it still takes quite a long time.

My current solution is to convert the data.table to a matrix and use the `apply()` function as:

```
similarity.matrix <- apply(m, 2, function(x) colSums(x == m)))/nrow(m)
```

However, the approach forces the modes of all elements to be the same, and I'd rather not have that happen. What other options do I have?

Here is a sample construction for the data.table:

```
m = matrix(sample(1:10, size=1000000, replace=TRUE), nrow=500, ncol=2000)
DF = as.data.frame(m)
DT = as.data.table(m)
```

Comment: Would you accept false positives in the result, I mean, do you check the possibly duplicated columns manually then? I could imagine of calculating one hash per column and the same hash value indicates possible duplicates.

Comment: Why not use `duplicated()`?

Comment: Thank you for the tip! duplicated() works wonders. It is much faster than my awkward approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Haboryme*, you can do this using `duplicated` to find any duplicated vectors. `duplicated` usually works rowwise, but you can transpose it with `t()` just for finding the duplicates.

```
DF <- DF[ , which( !duplicated( t( DF ) ) ) ]
```

With a `data.table`, you may need to add `with = FALSE` (I think this depends on the version of `data.table` you're using).

```
DT <- DT[ , which( !duplicated( t( DT ) ) ), with = FALSE ]
```

*@Haboryme, if you were going to turn your comment into an answer, please do and I'll remove this one.

Comment: Well done, the results are the non-duplicated column indices which is perfectly suited for further automatic processing!

Comment: Note that `duplicated` has a MARGIN argument for arrays, which could be used in place of `t`. like `duplicated.array(mtcars, MARGIN=2)`.

Comment: @rosscova thanks for the answer! This worked for me.

Comment: @Imo, right you are, I hadn't noticed that, thanks for the tip. Interestingly, I just did a few `microbenchmark` tests, and it doesn't seem any faster (on 1E5 rows and 1E3 columns + 1 dupe column, 204s with `t()` and 202s with `MARGIN=2`).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different approach, where you hash each column first and then call `duplicated`.

```
library(digest)
dups <- duplicated(sapply(DF, digest)) 
DF <- DF[,which(!dups)]
```

Depending on your data this might be a faster way.

Comment: good idea, the expense `duplicated` operation is working on one hash per column now and choosing a decent hash algorithm in `digest` could allow a trade off between hashing performance and hash collision density. Nor expensive transposing is required...

Comment: @mpjdem thank you for the pointer to digest. It didn't speed up my case but I'll definitely keep this in mind for later use.

Answer (score 2):

I am using mtcars for a reproducible result:

```
library(data.table)
library(digest)

# Create  data
data <- as.data.table(mtcars)
data[, car.name := rownames(mtcars)]
data[, car.name.dup := car.name]           # create a duplicated row
data[, car.name.not.dup := car.name]       # create a second duplicated row...
data[1, car.name.not.dup := "Moon walker"] # ... but change a value so that it is no longer a duplicated column
```

`data` contains now:

```
> head(data)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb          car.name      car.name.dup  car.name.not.dup
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4         Mazda RX4         Mazda RX4       Moon walker
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     Mazda RX4 Wag     Mazda RX4 Wag     Mazda RX4 Wag
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1        Datsun 710        Datsun 710        Datsun 710
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    Hornet 4 Drive    Hornet 4 Drive    Hornet 4 Drive
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet Sportabout Hornet Sportabout Hornet Sportabout
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1           Valiant           Valiant           Valiant
```

Now find the duplicated colums:

```
# create a vector with the checksum for each column (and keep the column names as row names)
col.checksums <- sapply(data, function(x) digest(x, "md5"), USE.NAMES = T)

# make a data table with one row per column name and hash value
dup.cols <- data.table(col.name = names(col.checksums), hash.value = col.checksums)

# self join using the hash values and filter out all column name pairs that were joined to themselves
dup.cols[dup.cols,, on = "hash.value"][col.name != i.col.name,]
```

Results in:

```
       col.name                       hash.value   i.col.name
1: car.name.dup 58fed3da6bbae3976b5a0fd97840591d     car.name
2:     car.name 58fed3da6bbae3976b5a0fd97840591d car.name.dup
```

**Note: The result still contains both directions (col1 == col2 and col2 == col1) and should be deduplicated ;-)**